# How to Filter NaNs before Displaying top N in dc.js?

Tags: javascript, dc.js, crossfilter

Straightforward question, but I haven't seen an answer anywhere. Basically, I want to filter my dataset for NaNs for a metric and then display the top 10 highest groups of that metric. I am using the fake group method, but I can't seem to use both top and filter for a bar chart.

```js
function remove_empty_bins(source_group) {
        return {
            all:function () {
                return source_group.top(10).filter(function(d) {
                    return ! isNaN(d.value.attendance_rate) ;
                });
            }
        };
    }
```

This code won't work since the top I believe only takes the top 10 sorted by key. If I want to sort by metric I would need to use chart.ordering() but obviously I can't use that because I need to sort before I do .top().

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I take it you are not using one of the charts that supports capping (pie, row). For those you should be able to just filter out the NaNs using a fake group, and then pass the data in.

Since 2.1.2, dc.js [has not used](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/pull/1184) `group.top()` internally for capped charts. The interaction between top and ordering was too confusing.

I would suggest approaching your problem the same way that those charts were changed. Instead of trying to use `group.top()` just do the sorting yourself. Then it's pretty easy to take all, filter, sort, and cap (untested):

```
function filter_sort_cap_bins(source_group) {
  return {
    all:function () {
      return source_group
        .all()
        .filter(d => !isNaN(d.value.attendance_rate))
        .sort((a,b) => b.value.attendance_rate - a.value.attendance_rate)
        .slice(0, 10);
    }
  };
}
```

Maybe in theory this is a little slower because it's working with the whole set of keys, but I don't think you'll notice any difference unless you have thousands of keys.

Comment: I really appreciate all your help on dc.js. It is super cool to see a dev so on top of things!

Comment: You're very welcome. Maintaining this library is a fascinating experience for me.

Comment: Thanks for the fix!